# fom validation is not working (only terms)

Tags: javascript

this code  is working but  terms is not working terms because i dont understand how to use checkbox for termsand condition

i dont understand how to use checkbox for termsand conditions  this code  is working but  terms is not working terms because

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#register").submit(function () {
    var x = $('#email').val();
    var atpos = x.indexOf("@");
    var dotpos = x.lastIndexOf(".");
    var passw = $('#password').val();
    var repassw = $('#repassword').val();

    if ($('#email').val() == "") {
      $('#email_error').html("Please Enter Email");
      return false;
    }

    if ($('#password').val() == "") {
      $('#email_error').html("");
      $('#password_error').html("Please Enter Password");
      return false;

    } else if ($('#repassword').val() == "") {
      $('#email_error').html("");
      $('#password_error').html("");
      $('#repassword_error').html("Please Re Enter Password");
      return false;

    } else if (passw != repassw) {
      $('#email_error').html("");
      $('#password_error').html("");
      $('#repassword_error').html("");
      $('#repassword_error').html("Please Re Enter Same Password");
      return false;

    } else if ($('#city').val() == '0') {
      $('#email_error').html("");
      $('#password_error').html("");
      $('#repassword_error').html("");
      $('#repassword_error').html("");
      $('#city_error').html("Please Choose your City");
      return false;

    } else if ($('#city').val() == '0') {
      $('#email_error').html("");
      $('#password_error').html("");
      $('#repassword_error').html("");
      $('#repassword_error').html("");
      $('#city_error').html("Please Choose your City");
      return false;

    } else if ($('#terms').val() = !checkbox.checked) {
      $('#email_error').html("");
      $('#password_error').html("");
      $('#repassword_error').html("");
      $('#repassword_error').html("");
      $('#city_error').html("");
      $('#terms').html("hello");
      return false;

    } else if (atpos < 1 || dotpos < atpos + 2 || dotpos + 2 >= x.length) {
      $('#email_error').html("");
      $('#password_error').html("");
      $('#repassword_error').html("");
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: please rephrase your question... it's like talking to yoda

Answer (score -1):

you can check, whether checkbox checked several ways

```
if($("#checkBoxId").is(':checked') == false){
    alert("not checked");
}
```

2.

```
if($("#checkBoxId").prop('checked') == false ){
    alert("not checked");
}
```

etc...